# SQL Server Query Returning Output Parameter As blank array

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following query is working fine in sql-explorer but when I am running using php sql_srv its giving blank array;

Query: I have tried using codeigniter lib also but nothing is working

```
Declare @Flag int,@EasyId varchar(50),@UserEmail varchar(50),@ST varchar(max),
@MSG varchar(max),@Name varchar(max),@REP_MOBILE varchar(max),@REP_EMAIL varchar(max),@REP_NAME varchar(max) 

EXEC [dbo].[USP_SS_WEB_UPDATE] 'UNHOLD',14880,'160114','JESSICA@BELGIUMGROUP.NET',@ST OUT, @MSG OUT

SELECT @Flag AS NumberChk,@ST AS [status],@MSG As [message],@Name AS [Name] ,@REP_MOBILE AS REP_MOBILE ,@REP_EMAIL AS REP_EMAIL ,@REP_NAME AS REP_NAME
```

Json of expected output

```
{
"Declare @Flag int,@EasyId varchar(50),@UserEmail varchar(50),@ST varchar(max),\n@MSG varchar(max),@Name varchar(max),@REP_MOBILE varchar(max),@REP_EMAIL varchar(max),@REP_NAME varchar(max) \n\nEXEC [dbo].[USP_SS_WEB_UPDATE] 'UNHOLD',14880,'160114','JESSICA@BELGIUMGROUP.NET',@ST OUT, @MSG OUT\n SELECT @Flag AS NumberChk,@ST AS [status],@MSG As [message],@Name AS [Name] ,@REP_MOBILE AS REP_MOBILE ,@REP_EMAIL AS REP_EMAIL ,@REP_NAME AS REP_NAME \n        \n": [
    {
        "NumberChk" : null,
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "holdstone,",
        "Name" : null,
        "REP_MOBILE" : null,
        "REP_EMAIL" : null,
        "REP_NAME" : null
    }
]}
```

php code:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    

if ( $conn )    
{    
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";    
}     
else     
{    
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.*/    

$sql = "Declare @Flag int,@EasyId varchar(50),@UserEmail varchar(50),@ST varchar(max),
@MSG varchar(max),@Name varchar(max),@REP_MOBILE varchar(max),@REP_EMAIL varchar(max),@REP_NAME varchar(max) 

EXEC [dbo].[USP_SS_WEB_UPDATE] 'UNHOLD',14880,'160114','JESSICA@BELGIUMGROUP.NET',@ST OUT, @MSG OUT

SELECT @Flag AS NumberChk,@ST AS [status],@MSG As [message],@Name AS [Name] ,@REP_MOBILE AS REP_MOBILE ,@REP_EMAIL AS REP_EMAIL ,@REP_NAME AS REP_NAME   ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      print_r($row);
}
```

Here is my CI mssql connection obj:

```
[subdriver] => 
[dbprefix] => 
[char_set] => utf8
[dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
[encrypt] => 
[swap_pre] => 
[port] => 
[pconnect] => 
[conn_id] => Resource id #3
[result_id] => Resource id #5
[db_debug] => 1
[benchmark] => 0.61152315139771
[query_count] => 2
[bind_marker] => ?
[save_queries] => 1
[queries] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT CASE WHEN (@@OPTIONS | 256) = @@OPTIONS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS qi
        [1] => Declare @Flag int,@EasyId varchar(50),@UserEmail varchar(50),@ST varchar(max),
```

@MSG varchar(max),@Name varchar(max),@REP_MOBILE varchar(max),@REP_EMAIL varchar(max),@REP_NAME varchar(max)

EXEC [dbo].[USP_SS_WEB_UPDATE] 'UNHOLD',14880,'160114','JESSICA@BELGIUMGROUP.NET',@ST OUT, @MSG OUT
 SELECT @Flag AS NumberChk,@ST AS [status],@MSG As [message],@Name AS [Name] ,@REP_MOBILE AS REP_MOBILE ,@REP_EMAIL AS REP_EMAIL ,@REP_NAME AS REP_NAME 
        )

```
[query_times] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.26295304298401
        [1] => 0.3485701084137
    )

[data_cache] => Array
    (
    )

[trans_enabled] => 1
[trans_strict] => 1
[_trans_depth:protected] => 0
[_trans_status:protected] => 1
[_trans_failure:protected] => 
[cache_on] => 
[cachedir] => 
[cache_autodel] => 
[CACHE] => 
[_protect_identifiers:protected] => 1
[_reserved_identifiers:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )

[_escape_char:protected] => "
[_like_escape_str:protected] =>  ESCAPE '%s' 
[_like_escape_chr:protected] => !
[_count_string:protected] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
[compress] => 
[stricton] => 
[failover] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Comment: everything is throwing blank array

Comment: i din't understand

Comment: print_r(sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)) Throwing blank array again

Comment: No luck.. again showing blank array

Comment: SQL Error [137] [S0002]: Must declare the scalar variable "@ST".

Comment: Check the result from the execution of the stored procedure: `DECLARE @rc int EXEC @rc = [dbo].[USP_SS_WEB_UPDATE] 'UNHOLD', 14880, '160114', 'JESSICA@BELGIUMGROUP.NET', @ST OUT, @MSG OUT IF @rc <> 0 BEGIN SET @ST = -1 SET @MSG = 'Error executing stored procedure' END`. Place this code in your sample (replace your EXEC statement with these lines).